# why and when should use a stack() and unstack() methods?

Tags: python, pandas, stack, data-science

I'm very confused about these two methods which are:
stack() and unstack()
I know that I should use them in the case of multi-Indexes however, I need to know the following:

1- I don't know where I should use stack or unstack
2- why I should use them

when I use "pivot" what I understand is that the pivot converts Dataframe to  be the unstack form, if that is correct so, I need to know why when I use the following line code it raises an error:

```
data.stack(level=1) # IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2
```

but when I do that following it runs:

```
data.unstack().stack(level=1)
```

sometimes, I see that stack has kwargs like so, level=-1 I don't know when I have to place "-1" and what does that mean

I know that I misunderstand a lot of stuff but I'm very confused

so, any help to understand these terms, please?

thx in advance

Comment: Have you had a look at the pandas docs regarding these methods?

Comment: yes I did but I still confused

Comment: sure, no worries. Kindly provide reproducible data you were practising with and the community will attempt to provide answers that should make things clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an attempt at a canonical answer on the differences between [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html). For a complete guide on reshaping, pandas's official documentation on [reshaping and pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) is a must read.

[`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) perform roughly the same operation, but they operate on different logical levels: **columns** and **index levels**, respectively.

I will use this example dataframe as input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ABCABC'),
                   'col2': list('aaabbb'),
                   'col3': list('uvwxyz'),
                  })
```

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    a    u
1    B    a    v
2    C    a    w
3    A    b    x
4    B    b    y
5    C    b    z
```

### Using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) on columns

`pandas.DataFrame.pivot` operates on columns

*NB. when the `index` argument if left unused, it will use the current index.*

```
df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3')
```

```
col2  a  b
col1      
A     u  x
B     v  y
C     w  z
```

### Using [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) on MultiIndexes

There are two use cases here whether the input is a Series or a DataFrame.

#### [`pandas.Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html)

We will generate first a Series with MultIndex from the initial DataFrame:

```
series = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])['col3']
```

```
col1  col2
A     a       u
B     a       v
C     a       w
A     b       x
B     b       y
C     b       z
Name: col3, dtype: object
```

We see that the data is very similar to the original DataFrame, but `col1` and `col2` are now index levels, and the data itself is now one-dimensional (i.e., a Series)

Now, we can apply `unstack` to pivot by default the right-most (last) index level as columns to generate a DataFrame. There are many ways to specify the index level to unstack so all these options are equivalent:

```
series.unstack()
```

```
series.unstack('col2') # by level name
```

```
series.unstack(1) # by level position from the left
```

```
series.unstack(-1) # by level position from the end (-1 = last)
```

```
col2  a  b
col1      
A     u  x
B     v  y
C     w  z
```

This means that `df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3')` and `df.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].unstack()` are logically equivalent.

#### [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

The DataFrame version of `unstack` is very similar to the Series's one, with the exception that, as the data is already two-dimensional, it will create an extra level of index for the columns.

```
df.set_index(['col1', 'col2']).unstack(level='col2')
```

```
     col3   
col2    a  b
col1        
A       u  x
B       v  y
C       w  z
```

Here again, the same output can be obtained using `pivot`, by passing a list-encapsulated column name to `values`:

```
df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values=['col3'])
```

```
     col3   
col2    a  b
col1        
A       u  x
B       v  y
C       w  z
```